# Actionscript 2.0 External SWF loaded and resized into Movieclip problem

Tags: actionscript-2

Even if I loaded for dozen times an external swf into a movieclip... I don`t know how to resize (layout) the targeted movieclip. I don`t mean the quality... Let`s say the external SWF has 400 X 300 px and I want it to be loaded into a movieclip container about 200X100. How to resize the external SWF file prior to be loaded? Please HELP ! I know that in AS 3 there is some code with x/y variables... But my external SWF and the main page (in whic I want the swf to be loaded) are in AS 2. Anyone pls Help :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Lets call the container SWF **mc_a** and the SWF to be loaded **mc_b**.

Create another container SWF inside **of mc_a**.  We'll call it **mc_c** for this discussion.

At runtime, set the visibility of **mc_c** to **false**.

Load **mc_b** into **mc_c**.

**mc_c** will assume the width and height of the loaded SWF, **mc_b**, but it will be invisible at this point.

Set the width and height of **mc_c** according to what you want.

Set the visibility of **mc_c** to **true**.

That should do it, or some similar variation of that.  You could also forgo the inner container, **mc_c**, and just set the visibility of **mc_a** to **false** at runtime, load **mc_b** into it, resize **mc_a** accordingly, and then set **mc_a**'s visibility to **true**.

The inner container method presumes you might have some other content in **mc_a** that you would not want resized.  When using the inner container method you might have to adjust the **x/y** of **mc_c** as well since it will scale anchored at the top left corner.

Comment: ok thanks man...I`ll try this... Hope that works. Ill notice you about that